# Shopware 6: Tax Free with domestic delivery in DE (TaxDecorator & CartRuleLoader)

Tags: shopware6

Some customers with a domestic shipping address within Germany are still tax exempt (e.g. NATO, or US Army).
Since this is considered an export delivery.

How can this be implemented? The only solution I have found is to completely override/replace `CartRuleLoader`

What I have done so far: I created a custom field in Customers, where a store editor can specify a customer as tax free (even within Germany).

Then I overwrote the class `TaxDetector`:

```
class TaxDetector extends \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Tax\TaxDetector
{

    public function isNetDelivery(SalesChannelContext $context): bool
    {
        $customer = $context->getCustomer();
        if ($customer && ($cf = $customer->getCustomFields()) && !empty($cf['mycustomfield']) && $cf['mycustomfield'] === 'nato') {
            return true;
        }

        return parent::isNetDelivery($context);
    }


    public function getTaxState(SalesChannelContext $context): string
    {
        $customer = $context->getCustomer();
        if ($customer && ($cf = $customer->getCustomFields()) && !empty($cf['mycustomfield']) && $cf['mycustomfield'] === 'nato') {
            return CartPrice::TAX_STATE_FREE;
        }

        return parent::getTaxState($context);
    }

}
```

The problem is that Shopware 6 checks the validity of the tax status in `CartRuleLoader` when completing an order. And here the test is done in private functions that I cannot override.

```
load -> validateTaxFree -> detectTaxType
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this more eligant and futerprove then override all `CartRuleLoader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a little tricky.

When you look at the method `CartRuleLoader::detectTaxType` you can find these lines:

```php
$currency = $context->getCurrency();
$currencyTaxFreeAmount = $currency->getTaxFreeFrom();
$isReachedCurrencyTaxFreeAmount = $currencyTaxFreeAmount > 0 && $cartNetAmount >= $currencyTaxFreeAmount;

if ($isReachedCurrencyTaxFreeAmount) {
    return CartPrice::TAX_STATE_FREE;
}
```

It's arguably a little hacky but you could "trick" Shopware to return the tax free state by setting the tax free amount of the currency to a minimal amount.

Therefore you could decorate `Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactory`.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactoryDecorator" decorates="Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactory" decoration-priority="-999">
    <argument type="service" id="MyPlugin\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\SalesChannelContextFactoryDecorator.inner"/>
</service>
```

In the decorator you could then have your logic and set the tax free amount:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace MyPlugin\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context;

use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Price\Struct\CartPrice;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Context\AbstractSalesChannelContextFactory;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;

class SalesChannelContextFactoryDecorator extends AbstractSalesChannelContextFactory
{
    private AbstractSalesChannelContextFactory $decorated;

    public function __construct(
        AbstractSalesChannelContextFactory $decorated,
    ) {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public function getDecorated(): AbstractSalesChannelContextFactory
    {
        return $this->decorated;
    }

    public function create(string $token, string $salesChannelId, array $options = []): SalesChannelContext
    {
        $context = $this->getDecorated()->create($token, $salesChannelId, $options);
        
        // ... your logic
        if (...) {
            $context->getCurrency()->setTaxFreeFrom(0.00001);
            $context->setTaxState(CartPrice::TAX_STATE_FREE);
        }   
        
        return $context;
    }
}
```

Edit: It looks like this could not be enough as there is a security check which checks if the previous state wasn't tax free and resets it otherwise.

```php
if ($previous !== CartPrice::TAX_STATE_FREE) {
    $context->setTaxState($previous);
}
```

You might have to additionally set the tax state inside your decorator (updated the above example). The tax free amount would then make it stick.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a bit hacky :-)
I just thought of a separate country "Germany / NATO".
Then customers with this country would be considered as non-EU / export delivery.
However, I would then have to prevent users from selecting "NATO" as a country in the profile itself. I don't know. Seems all a bit workaround...

Comment: Yes, there is no great solution for this at the moment unfortunately.  This would be a great use case for the rule builder. I will suggest adding that functionality. In the meanwhile maybe try with this solution nonetheless. Decorating the `SalesChannelContextFactory` isn't as bad as it seems, it's also done in the core for a cache decorator. The real workaround here is using `setTaxFreeFrom` to make the state stick.